# Currency format

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

i have a issue with some string formats, i'm forcing the culture when formatting specific formats:

```
get { return String.Format("{0:###,###,###,###,##0}", Convert.ToDecimal(_monthPay, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"))); }
```

so that i can get this:

$300.000,01

On localhost it works fine, but when i publish to the server, i get this:

$300,000.01

I don't know why!!! I don't have access to the server, so I can't change the regional settings on the server; is there another way to solve it? so that i works properly on localhost and when publishing?

Thanks.

Comment: what server? What language? Questions seems to be incomplete.

Comment: You ought to tag this with C# for it to get attention from the audience best able to answer it.

Comment: How is this related to currency?

Comment: your current format string will also truncate your decimals.  You'd need to add ...##0.## or ...##0.00 to the end in order to not drop those digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is telling the Convert.ToDecimal function what _monthPay will look like.  What you're expecting is that the String will be formatted with the culture info.

You should be telling String.Format what culture to use:

```
String.Format( new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"), "{0:###,###,###,###,##0.##}", Convert.ToDecimal(_monthPay)));
```

Answer (score 5):

You're passing the `CultureInfo` in the wrong place.

By passing the `CultureInfo` to `Convert.ToDecimal`, you're telling `Convert.ToDecimal` to convert the number using that culture.  (This is relevant if `_monthPay` is a string and needs to be parsed)
However, you didn't pass a `CultureInfo` to `String.Format`, so it is still using the default culture.

By the way, you should only use `String.Format` if you're combining multiple values.  In your case, you should call the `ToString` overload.  Also, your format string is needlessly long; you can simply write `#,0`.  If you want to include a currency symbol, you can simply use `C` instead.

Therefore, you should write `Convert.ToDecimal(_monthPay).ToString("#,0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"))`.

Comment: You can also pass the `CultureInfo` as the first argument to `String.Format`: `String.Format(new CultureInfo("es-ES"), "{0:###,###,###,###,##0}", value)`

Comment: Yes, but he shouldn't be using `String.Format` in the first place.

Comment: Honestly he doesn't need the huge format string either.  He can replace it with a single "C" to get a currency format.

Comment: He doesn't (seem) to want a currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
```

Try putting that in some initialization block.

Answer (score 1):

```
get 
{ 
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
    return Convert
        .ToDecimal(_monthPay, culture)
        .ToString("###,###,###,###,##0", culture); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the really long custom format, what about the built-in format for currency?

```
get { return Convert.ToDecimal(_monthPay).ToString("C", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")); }
```

EDIT:  moved the culture info.. I still don't think using some massive format string is right.  There are built-in format conventions for currency...